# Why was post-increment and post-decrement not made a language defined construct?

Tags: c++

What is the point of leaving it up to the developer? Every post-increment and post-decrement is implemented the same way. And implementing it in any other way would raise some questions. So why not leave it to the compiler to do the job?

Though I feel I'm missing some use case.

**Update**

I think every post-increment is implemented like this

```
struct S{
    int x = 0;
    S& operator ++ () { ++x; return *this; }
    S operator ++ (int) { S r = *this; ++x; return r; }
};
```

If that is so, than we should not write our own `operator ++ (int)`, but the compiler should generate this code with the following pattern

```
T operator ++ (int) { T r = *this; ++(*this); return r; }
```

Comment: Perhaps you could show us some examples that make you think this can only ever be implemented in one way.

Comment: Just because you can't think of a use case does not mean there is no use case.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "not a language defined construct"?

Comment: How do you increment any arbitrary class instance? What does it mean to increment a string for instance?

Comment: @Ayxan, I'm talking about post-increment(decrement), which would only work if you have pre- version defined.

Comment: @Adler This is just operator overloading. You can in principal overload any operator to do anything you want, without regards to convention. Look at how the bitshift operator was reused for streaming by `std::cout` and `std::cin`. It's a language feature to be able to redefine the meaning of operators.

Comment: @Adler again, you are making an assumption that is simply not true. It is not a requirement to implement one in terms of the other. That is just common practice to reduce code duplication, but it is certainly possible to implement them separately in very different ways, as long as the correct semantics are observed

Comment: Adler, I think I see where you are coming from. I think you should update the question to ask something more like, "If I have a preincrement, why can't the compiler generate the post increment?"

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux, but here I'm we're talking about post-increment(decrement), which, following the logic, are based on pre- version. Meaning, by implementing pre- version, you already implement post- version

Comment: @user4581301, fair point. But what I was really hoping for is to see some examples where one would need to manually write a post-increment(decrement)

Comment: @Adler What if the class is move-only? The operators can be made to do anything and forcing one particular implementation would not be great. For instance,  shift operators mean something different to most stream classes and the division operator means something different to `std::filesystem::path`.

Comment: People come up with weird classes. For example [analog literals](http://www.eelis.net/C++/analogliterals.xhtml). I'm not saying this is a perfect counter example but it illustrate that it's hard to imagine how far people will push things. Sometimes operators aren't used in the way you might expect.

Comment: @Ayxan, but again. The point I'm trying to make is that it would be surprising to see a version of post-increment(decrement) which is not based on the pre- version. And unless there's a concrete and legitimate example where one would need write their own post- version, this is all pointless talk. And still though, if there's a couple of example where one would need to write the post- operator manually, it's still not clear why not make it compiler-generated, as with copy-constructor and `operator =`

Comment: Save from having B Stroustrup himself answers I fear you can have only speculations and a posteriori justifications.  The subject is not handled in Design and Evolution of C++ which is the main published rationale for design decisions.

Comment: Your generated code requires copy assignment or copy contructor. I could create a class with increment operator with deleted copy operators.

Answer (score 4):

Bearing in mind that operator-overloading design predates standard support for atomic operations, consider that many systems could support a limited range of atomic primitives, and programs for such systems could include classes to implement them.  If `a` is supposed to behave as an atomic `int`, then a statements like `x=a++;` and `y=++a;` would have a meaning significantly different from `(x=a),(a++);` or `(++a),(y=a)`.  On a platform with an `atomic_post_increment()` function, one could use `x=atomic_post_increment(&a); y=atomic_post_increment()+1;`, and on one with `atomic_pre_increment()`, one could use `x=atomic_pre_increment(&a)-1; y=atomic_pre_increment(&a);`, but emulating whichever operation isn't directly supported in terms of whichever one is directly supported would be better than requiring that post-increment always be emulated in terms of pre-increment, or pre-increment in terms of post-increment.

Answer (score 2):

Your idea of automated generation of operators are very limited to numeric types and also restricts in general that the meaning of the operator is in "some kind" guaranteed.

But it is absolutely legal to write anything behind the interface of an user defined operator for any user defined type.

As an example I create my own library which do not calculate the results in place of the operator call but stores the operation "somewhere" and execute it every time the variable is modified later. The operator simply creates a observer which is called every time the var is modified and do the operation if called later. The operator itself is observable simply by writing it inside any other term. Quite simple but breaks your "rule" of automated operator generation.

Operator overloading is a perfect tool for generating user defined languages. As this, any restriction to operator overloading would decrease the power of the language feature.

Answer (score 0):

`operator++` is not unique in this regard.

Take for instance `operator<`. One could argue that operators >, <=, >= could all be generated by the compiler in terms of `operator<`:

```
struct foo { 
    bool operator<(const foo& other) const {
        return /* actual comparison */;
    }

    bool operator>(const foo& other) const {
        return other < *this;
    }

    bool operator<=(const foo& other) const {
        return *this > other;
    }

    bool operator>=(const foo& other) const {
        return *this < other;
    }

};
```

In general, if you have an `operator<`, one could argue that operators >,<=, and >= should be implemented like this.

The thing is, if C++ did that, it would remove flexibility. What if one day you had a good reason (you probably don't have a good reason, but assume you did) to implement these differently than above? What if there is one specific case, out of the 1000s of cases where you need to implement this differently? The answer is you couldn't.

C++ generally attempts to provide power, in exchange for "safety," so to speak. So even though it would be "safer" to force an implementation, it would also decrease the extend-ability in the language.

---

Another example of this are operators == and !=.